# Splitting a heap at given key

Tags: python, heap

Given a list: [10, 4, 9, 3, 2, 5, 8, 1, 0]

that has the heap structure of below:

```
        8
    9
        5
10
        2
    4
            0
        3
            1
```

What is a good algorithm in python to get [4,3,2,1,0] which is basically the left child of 10.

parent is (index+1)//2

left child is 2i+1, right child is 2i+2

```
L = [10, 4, 9, 3, 2, 5, 8, 1, 0]
index = 1
newheap = []
newheap.append(L[index])
leftc = 2 * index + 1
rightc = 2 * index + 2
while(leftc < len(L)):
    newheap.append(L[leftc])
    if(rightc < len(L)):
        newheap.append(L[rightc])
    leftc = 2 * leftc + 1
    rightc = 2 * rightc + 2

print(newheap)
```

which outputs

```
[4,3,2,1]
```

but I need [4,3,2,1, 0], so not what I wanted. I started the index at 1 which points to 4.

Would recursion be better? Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
L = [10, 4, 9, 3, 2, 5, 8, 1, 0]
index = 0
offset = 1
newheap = []
while index < len(L):
    index += offset
    for i in range(offset):
        if index+i == len(L):
            break
        newheap += [L[index+i]]
    offset = 2 * offset
print(newheap)
```